# How to use C# console for input and logging at the same time

Tags: javascript, c#, node.js, console

I have got a C# console application. I'm starting up another cmd process to use my NodeJS app (maybe any advise on how to do this otherwise? I have to run both at the same time, they work togheter).

Now the NodeJS process its output is streamed to my C# console.

```
private readonly Process _nodeProcess = new Process
{
    StartInfo =
    {
        FileName = "cmd",
        Arguments = @"/K Node server.js",
        UseShellExecute = false,
        RedirectStandardOutput = true
    }
};

internal void Start()
{
    _nodeProcess.Start();
    using (StreamReader reader = _nodeProcess.StandardOutput)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            string result = reader.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine(result);
        }
    }
}
```

This works fine.
Now the problem here is, my Node logs something, but meanwhile I want to be able to give commands (input) on my console.

Example of my console output: (of course it uses a whole system, outputting real stuff..)

```
NodeJS process started
node log 1
node log 2
node log ...
```

and so on ..

But while it keeps outputting my log lines, I want to be able to type (for command input) with `Console.ReadLine();`. This without the risk of typing inside the same line as an output line.

I would appreciate any help. Any suggestions on improving my code are welcome.

Answer (score 2):

In your case it would be better to handle the output **Asynchronously**.

First add an Eventhandler to your Output:

```
_nodeProcess.OutputDataReceived += (s, e) => Console.WriteLine(e.Data);
```

Then add the line `_nodeProcess.BeginOutputReadLine();` after `_nodeProcess.Start();`

Something like:

```
 _nodeProcess.OutputDataReceived += (s, e) => Console.WriteLine(e.Data);
 _nodeProcess.Start();
 _nodeProcess.BeginOutputReadLine();

 var line = Console.ReadLine();
 while (line != null && line.ToLower() != "exit")
 {
      line = Console.ReadLine();
 }
 _nodeProcess.Close();
```

Comment: It does output and maintain the input, but then I get things like:
`input string node log 1` or even `input strnode log 1` and on the next line `ing` ...

Also I want the input to be on my main console.. not on my node process.. :( otherwise I will have nested systems all the way..

Comment: I've ignored your while loop, it now keeps outputting, and in the main console I've put the `Console.ReadLine();` i wanted. This way I can have my commands as input on the main console. I'm controlling this node process from my console, not from this process itself.

Comment: Ok great, Happy that it works. I guess the point I wanted to make was that you needed to use the Asynchronous output to enable the 'Console.ReadLine();'

Comment: I already encountered the Async functions, but forgot about it a little (stupid me). Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.
Problem I have now, is that my Node service is not really stopped when I exit and leave my console open, and that any input might be interuppted with output on the same line.. any ideas?